# Calculating the p-value in an event study

Tags: p-value

I am in the process of doing an event study with an R package from https://www.eventstudytools.com/. The analysis works so far, but I have a question about the interpretation of the different significance tests. All tests used in the package are listed here: https://www.eventstudytools.com/significance-tests.

How can I calculate the respective p values of the significance tests?

- Patell Test (Patell Z)
- Standardized Cross-Sectional Test (StdCSect Z)
- Corrado Rank Test (Rank Z)
- Cowan Generalized Sign Test (Generalized Sign Z)

[Example with four different tests and the respective values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3PpW.png)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't understand. The link you give there has the definitions of the test statistics for each of the tests and the sampling distribution of the test stat under the null. Are you asking for an implementation of these stats using R code?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not clear to me how to calculate the correct p-value in R using the information on the website. The package does not give the p-value directly. I have to calculate it based on the value of the respective test.